# Clear call history of a mock

Tags: rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

**question**: is it possible to clear the call history of a mock (or stub)? 
( and with call history I don't mean the expected / recorded behaviour.)

**The details:**
I currently want am writing the following code with tests according the AAA syntax using NUnit and Rhino mocks.

```cs
public abstract class MockA
{
    private bool _firstTime = true;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (_firstTime)
        {
            OnFirstDoSomething();
            _firstTime = false;
        }
    }

    public abstract void OnFirstDoSomething();
}

[TestFixture]
public class MockATest
{
    [Test]
    public void DoSomethingShouldSkipInitializationForSequentialCalls()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockA = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MockA>();
        mockA.Expect(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething()).Repeat.Any();
        mockA.DoSomething();  // -> OnFirstDoSomething() is called
        // here I want clear the call history of mockA 

        //Act
        mockA.DoSomething(); // -> OnFirstDoSomething should NOT be called
        mockA.DoSomething(); // -> OnFirstDoSomething should NOT be called

        //assert
        mockA.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething());
    }
}
```

For the readability I always try to focus the calls in the Assert section on the changes that occur within the Act section. 
However, the arrange section in this test, contains a (required) action that influence the call history of mockA. 
As a result the assert fails.

I known I could catch a 'change' in the call history using the construction below, but it makes the expected behaviour of this test less readable.

```cs
{
    ...
    mockA.AssertWasCalled(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething(), opt => opt.Repeat.Once());
    //Act
    mockA.DoSomething();
    //Assert
    mockA.AssertWasCalled(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething(), opt => opt.Repeat.Once());
}
```

**My question**: is it possible to clear the call history of a mock (not recorded Expectations)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear call history. Use Stub method instead of Expect in Arrange section:

```
[Test]
public void DoSomethingShouldSkipInitializationForSequentialCalls()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockA = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<MockA>();

    // this is what you have to change
    mockA.Stub(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething()).Repeat.Any();
    mockA.DoSomething();  // -> OnFirstDoSomething() is called
    // here I want clear the call history of mockA 

    //Act
    mockA.DoSomething();
    mockA.DoSomething();

    //assert
    mockA.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.OnFirstDoSomething());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this won't work. I added code of 'MockA' and some comment in the test to clear the expected behaviour.

Comment: After several years of TDD , I decided to try-out another mock framewerk NSubstitute. One of the things I noticed is that the mocks call history can be cleared is I wanted with Rhinomock.